# Can I supply a custom Vertex and Fragment shader to my Android Canvas object?

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es

I'd like to be able to use the Android Canvas object to draw my images.  Like so:

```
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawRGB(250, 250, 250);
canvas.drawBitmap(logo, 100, 100, null);
```

But I would also like to be able to use a custom vertex and fragment shader on that same canvas such that I can set the uniforms on the shader but let the Canvas do the work of setting up the quad, sizing the sprite, supplying the texture coordinates, and such.

Is there a way to use an Android Canvas object and a custom shader together?